# How can I add multiple items to the Quick Buy menu?

Tags: dota-2

For example; I want to have *Phase Boots* + *Bracers* in the quick buy menu, but when I add bracers, the phase boots disappear.

Comment: i do not see any command to set quickbuy to handle 2 items at once. based on this command list: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Console_Command_List .

Comment: This might help: gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53286/how-to-script-autobuy-of-specific-items/53482#53482

Answer (score 20):

**Update:**

As of the 2016 Spring Cleaning update, you can now append items to quick by using  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Mouseclick. An example of this can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAt1n.jpg). Thanks to Ashvin Panicker for the update.

**Previous answer:**

Simply, you cannot. Just try to prioritise what you wish to buy in which order. It is unlikely that you will need to buy your bracer AND phase boots in a very short amount of time. In which case I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of Quick buy a little bit. Binding the quick-buy to a key means that you can buy items fast when, for example, you're about to die.

Alternative solution: Use the pencil icon on the shop to create your own customised recommended items list. You can therefore add the items you're more likely to buy, and avoid searching the shop for them.

Comment: This is NOT TRUE

Comment: What is not true? And please remember that my answer was written in 2014. If there is an update that affects the answer please specify.

Comment: You CAN add items to quickbuy. I apologize for not noticing that you had answered this in 2014. This feature actually came with the Spring Cleaning Update(2016). This is infact in the patch notes:-
"Added support (Ctrl-Shift click) for appending to the quickbuy panel to add individual items"

[Example Image](http://imgur.com/xzvqX7k)

Comment: Nice! I'll add it to my answer and credit you :)

Answer (score 2):

**Add Quickbuy (1 item)**: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click on item

**Append* to Quickbuy**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click on item

- *Append*= (add after the items already in quickbuy)

So for phase boots and bracer, You can Shift click phase boots then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click Bracer

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can,

Press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> on the first item you want to add, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> on the second and they will be both added.